# Why does the HTML "lang" attribute change font ligatures and how can I avoid this?

Tags: html, css, fonts, multilingual

On the website I'm currently developing, I'm using the font [EB Garamond](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ebgaramond-otf) for some text. It's a multi-language website with a language switcher that toggles the `lang` attribute of the `<html>` element between `"en"` and `"de"`.

On the English version, the text has ligatures. On the German version, it doesn't. If I go to "Inspect Element" on the German version and change the `lang` attribute to `en`, the ligatures appear.

I can turn *off* the ligatures on the English version by applying the CSS rule `font-variant-ligatures: none;`. However, turning them *on* in the German version with `font-variant-ligatures: normal;` doesn't work (not even with `!important`).

I would like to have the ligatures *on* in both languages. Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this, and why it behaves in such a weird way in the first place?

Here's my font-related CSS code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: garamond;
    src: url(../fonts/eb-garamond/EBGaramond-Regular.otf);
}
```

```css
.garamond {
    font-family: garamond;
}

h1 {
    @apply text-4xl font-bold;
}

p {
    @apply mb-2;
}

.lead {
    @apply text-xl;
}
```

(just fyi, the `@apply` stuff applies classes from TailwindCSS, see [font size](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size), [font weight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-weight) and [margin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin), but that should be irrelevant to the question)

And the HTML / Twig:

```html
<div class="text-center garamond">
    <h1>{{ "SITE_TITLE"|t|e }}</h1>
    <p class="lead">{{ "SITE_SUBTITLE"|t|e }}</p>
</div>
```

And here's what the English version looks like:
[Screenshot English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4jES.png)

And the German:
[Screenshot German](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ucu.png)

Comment: did you try that in different browsers/OS? Does it happen in all of them?

Comment: According to http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/de/features.html it's a "feature" of the font, "[the German] locale prevents undesirable ligatures like ffl, fb, fh etc.". If you need the ligatures for some elements, you can always set their `lang` attribute to `""`.

Comment: "Because it has to"? If you specify `lang="de"` the text should have different ligatures compared to `lang="en"` because _those languages are not written the same way_. Why would you bypass that and make the content look objectively wrong for German readers? The `lang` attribute tells the browser what localization should be applied, if any, and "making sure the written text follows that locale's rules for written text" is one of the most important ones.

Comment: Hm. I didn't realize these ligatures were considered "undesirable" in German. German is my native language, and to my eye, the version *without* ligatures is actually the one that looks wrong. Thank you for pointing this out, but I'll still go for some workaround since this particular text is more of a design element that should look consistent across languages.

Comment: FWIW: The fi ligature definitely doesn't look wrong to me, and I am also a German (actually Austrian) reader. It's rather a matter of taste if one likes it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f-ligatures are generally undesirable in German typography because they usually occur across compound words like the *fl* in *auflagen* or the *fb* in *laufband*. Some typographers follow the same rule in English as well, and some go further to avoid ligatures that would join two *syllables* together.

EB Garamond was designed by a German-speaking type designer who included localization features so that f-ligatures are completely disabled in texts that are flagged as German. If you want to manually apply ligatures to German text, don't change the `lang=` property to `"en"` or `""`. You can simply turn off the OpenType `locl` feature for a single word like this:

```
<h1 lang="de"><span class="de-liga">schachingerfilm</span> kamera und postproduktion</h1>
```

```
.de-liga {
  font-feature-settings: 'locl' 0;
}
```

This would effectively apply the `liga` OpenType feature to the *fi* in *schachingerfilm* because the `locl` feature is no longer preventing it.

Comment: Does Safari support `font-feature-settings: "locl" 0;`? According to _MDN/Can I use_ `font-feature-settings` is fully supported in Safari but I can't disable localized forms (`locl`) on iOS. It does work in Chrome, Edge and Firefox on Windows and Android.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: The `lang` attribute can be used on single tags, which for example is done with `<span lang="en">` tags around single words or phrases to get proper pronounciation of English words in German texts when read by a screen reader.

So if you only need that for example on a certain `h1` in your page, you could use it like this...

```
<h1 lang="en">schachingerfilm</h1>
```

... and still have `lang="de"` or an according variable in your `body`tag.

(I guess the proper screen reader pronounciation in this case is not that important for you... ;-)

Comment: Is "schachingerfilm" an English word? If not please don't set `lang` to `"en"`, use the unknown value to disable it (`""`)

Comment: @Kaiido "schachingerfilm" is the company name. So it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It does. If it's not in a particular language use unknown. Why should screen-readers use an English voice to read this?